# Why are Lucene/Elasticsearch prefix queries slower than term queries?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, solr, lucene, inverted-index

I've been recently reading about Lucene and Elasticsearch and it seems the following are true (correct me if i'm wrong):

1. prefix queries are slower than term queries
2. suffix queries (* ing) are slower than prefix queries (ing *)

This seems like a strange combination of properties. Perhaps I need to broaden my scope of data structures I'm considering, but if a segment were structured like a hash table, I could easily see that 1 would be true (the term query would be O(1) and a prefix query would require a full scan) however 2 would not be true (both prefix and suffix would require a full scan). If the segment were laid out like a sorted array, I could easily see that 2 would be true (a prefix query could be performed with a binary search O(log n) and the suffix would require a full scan) however 1 would no longer be true (both a term and prefix query would require a binary search).

My only other thought is that there might be some combination of both hash and sort going on to account for this behavior (ex. hash to some partition and sort within that partition). However my understanding is that Elasticsearch partitions by a document identifier but the inverted index key is a term. So a query for a term still requires the request being sent to all partitions.

Can anyone provide me with some intuition as to how/why this behavior exists?

Note:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5RmMNDR5XI would suggest that a segment is structured similar to a sorted array rather than a hash table.
- The reason I believe 1 is true is https://medium.com/@mourjo_sen/a-detailed-comparison-between-autocompletion-strategies-in-elasticsearch-66cb9e9c62c4 mentions "The most important reason why prefix-like queries should never be used in production environments is that they are extremely slow. The reason for this is that the tokens in ES are not directly prefix-able"
- The reason I believe 2 is true is https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html mentions "Allowing a wildcard at the beginning of a word (eg "*ing") is particularly heavy, because all terms in the index need to be examined, just in case they match

Comment: To add on to my note for why I believe 1 is true. This must be the case, or else why would people bother with EdgeNGrams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with ES specific details so they might be doing something else than plain Solr - but #1 is not the case usually.

A prefix match will be more expensive than looking up a single term, but it's not *that* much more expensive. It can be compared to doing a range search (which you can perform if you want to - `field:[aa TO ab)` could be compared to doing `field:aa*` (in theory); effectively retrieving all tokens that lie within that range, then resolving the document set that matches those tokens.

The fact that there are more tokens that match means that you can't simply take the list attached to a single token (a matching term) and retrieve those documents, but you have to retrieve a possibly large set of matching tokens and then compute the document set for that. However, this is not a *very expensive* computation, but it is more expensive than just a single match. The lookup can be done by finding the starting and end indexed of the matching tokens in the index, then retrieving all terms between those two and find the set of matching document ids.

A query of `foo*` against an indexed with the following terms:

```
bar, baz, foo, foobar, spam
          ^----------^
```

will collect the list of documents attached to `foo` and `foobar`, merge it and then retrieve the documents.

Slower does not mean that it's catastrophic or not optimised in any way; just that it's more expensive than a direct match where the set of documents has already been determined. However, you probably have more than one term in your query already, so the same process (albeit slightly higher up in the hierarchy) happens there as well.

A postfix match (your #2) - i.e. matching a wildcard at the beginning of the token - is expensive, since all tokens in the index usually has to be considered. The index have the terms sorted alphanumerically, so when you want to only look at the end of the string you have to consider that each token could match, regardless of where it's located in the index - so you get a full index scan. However, if this is a use case you see happening often, you can use [the reverse wildcard filter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#reversed-wildcard-filter). This works by reversing the string and having tokens that match the terms in reverse order, so that `foo` is indexed as `oof` and a wildcard search gets turned into `oof*` instead.

A query of `*ar` against an indexed with the following terms:

```
bar, baz, foo, foobar, spam
?!   ?    ?    ?!      ?
```

will have to look at each term to decide if it ends with `ar`.

The reason for using an EdgeNGramFilter (your comment / #3) is that you move as much of the required processing as possible to indexing time (doing the work that you know do query time, even if prefix queries aren't really expensive, they still have a cost), and additionally: wildcard queries does not support most analysis. So many people end up with wildcard queries against a set of tokens that have been stemmed or otherwise processed, and are then surprised when their wildcard queries doesn't generate a match. Only a small subset of filters can be applied to wildcard queries (such as the LowercaseFilter). Those filters are known as [being "Multi term aware"](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SOLR/MultitermQueryAnalysis), since the terms the process can end up being expanded to multiple terms before collection of documents happen.

Another reason is that using an EdgeNGramFilter will give you proper frequency scores for each prefix, giving you effective scoring for prefixed terms as well.

Comment: This makes a tremendous amount of sense, thank you! The article i referenced (https://medium.com/@mourjo_sen/a-detailed-comparison-between-autocompletion-strategies-in-elasticsearch-66cb9e9c62c4) mentioned "...prefix-like queries should never be used in production environments is that they are extremely slow. The reason for this is that the tokens in ES are not directly prefix-able. So Elasticsearch has to check every token at runtime to see if it starts with the required text." from what you've said this doesn't see to be true. You'd only analyze all tokens within the range. is that right?

Comment: You don't analyze tokens; tokens are the result of the tokenizer and then processed through analysis before being stored. The input text is analyzed and filtered, and the resulting tokens are stored in the Lucene index. I'm not familiar enough with the details of Elasticsearch to say what the article is referencing, but from what the article says it talks about `match_prefix_queries`, which is a different feature from prefixed queries with wildcards (which you can see from it expanding to maximum 25 values _and_ performing analysis, neither which is what a wildcard prefix query would do).

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks for the answer! But do you know any profits using prefix query against field analyzed with edge ngrams? From what I understand it should speed up the process, because we will have the term we need in the inverted index. I experimented with edge ngrams and found no significant difference between prefix, match and querystring queries for my prefix scenarios (requested prefix is a single word, no analyze required for it). Index was pretty big with almost 50 millions medium size documents.